# Is it possible to disable CNI, ONLY on Openshift Master?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Folks,

I have a Openshift cluster that has 1 Master and 2 Compute nodes.

```
Openshift Version: 3.9

Deployment Type: Origin
```

Openshift SDN network plugin type is: CNI

Per Openshift documentation [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/infrastructure_components/web_console.html), Web Console pod should run on the Master node. So my ose-install lists Master as one of the "nodes" as well:

```
[nodes]
x.x.x.x openshift_hostname=foo <---- master
y.y.y.y openshift_hostname=bar <---- compute 1
z.z.z.z openshift_hostname=zoo <---- compute 2
```

I wish to run Web Console pod on the Master in host-networking mode ONLY.
So, I DO NOT wish to install CNI on the master.

But, since Master is also a "node" in ose-install, Openshift seems to expect that CNI will be installed on the Master. If not, it complains that the Master is NotReady and hence Master node is not schedulable. This results in web-console pod not being scheduled on the Master node.

If I manually edit openshift node config and remove networkConfig from it and restart openshift-node on Master, then Master comes up as Ready and all is fine. However such manual intervention is "not clean".

Is there a way, we can achieve "NO CNI" on master via a knob in ose-install ?

If there are alternate suggestions, I am absolutely all ears.

Appreciate your inputs. Thank You.